# How do I update an Immutable array in a React/Redux environment?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a React application that I'm using Redux to manage state.  I have the reducer working correctly, and I've successfully, passed the action and data I need. The problem is, up to this point, I've only worked with strings, so I've been using the `.set` method to update the state.

Now, I need to update an array by a specific index number, but I'm not having any luck.

Through my research, I've tried utilizing the `.update` method, but that's not working for me either. Another solution suggested mapping the state and modifying the index number, but that seemed a bit overkill.

Here is what I have for my state object:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
    items: []
});
```

Through a `componentWillMount` function, I populate the items array using an AJAX call successfully by calling `state.set('items', action.items);`

Now, I can't figure out how to update a single item in that array by an index number. I was able to get the index number using Immutable, but I don't know how to properly update the single array object.

My reducer is setup like so:

```
function reducerName(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_COMPLETED:
            let index = state.get('items').findIndex( (item) => { return item.id === action.reminder_id});
            return state
                .setIn(['items', index, 'completed'], true)
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can update a single index within the array instead of the entire array?

Comment: What is inside your actions to work with in that case? Is the index provided or to be determined at that point in time? Please show what is on the action.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes I have the index available. I edited the above to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have the index and updated information on your action,i if you don't, you will need a different approach... but it would be Something like this using [setIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/setIn) :

```
function reducerName(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_COMPLETED:
        return state
            .setIn(['items', action.index], action.updatedData)

  }
}
```

See this fiddle for a simple example - https://jsfiddle.net/o04btr3j/276/

Comment: What if the array is filled with objects and I need to update a specific property? So, if the object was `{name: "John Doe", completed: false}` how would I update just the completed property?

Comment: @TomNolan add to that initial array, so if you wanted to updated item[index].completed to whatever you just change it to `.setIn(['items', action.index, 'completed']` - see this updated fiddle for reference, https://jsfiddle.net/o04btr3j/279/

Comment: When I switch to that, I'm getting an `invalid keyPath` error and that's all the error says...any ideas?

Comment: @TomNolan you need to show the full code ... That normally means you have a path wrong or are using the set or update wrong. I don't know if you are referring to my answer or the answer in the comments, which are 2 separate questions...

Comment: I've updated my code above to show what I have, I added what you described above. I'm currently just passing `true` because all are `false` by default, and I was just trying to get a result.  

The `initialState` const was also updated to show that it is immutable

Comment: @TomNolan I believe the issue is with your index, not the code I have provided  - see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o04btr3j/280/ . Console.log that index and make sure you have an actual number in there.

Comment: I've console logged that index several times, and it always returns the correct index

Comment: That is modifying the list const directly, does anything change when it's actually the redux state object?

Comment: @TomNolan that invalid keypath error generally means you are giving an invalid immutable path. Sometimes it can be that you dont have the items quoted in that array, or are providing a wrong type of path. Are you sure that the index is a `number` or `int` and **not** a string? Also on a side note, the index can be a const instead of a let because it's not going to change in that function. Also if you can maybe throw your stuff in a jsfiddle or whatever you prefer, it might be easier to debug.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's an `int` and just to be sure, I did use an actual number instead of the `const` for a test

Comment: @TomNolan I'm not sure what to tell you then. I've given you 3 separate working examples. The first of which solved your initial problem. Might be best to ask a new question and make sure you put in all relevant code. A js fiddle or something would be extremely helpful to help you out because the problem you are having now could be one of many things. You don't your whole app in there, just the state going into it and what you want out of it. That is assuming your problem is only the reducer, it's a bit hard to tell from this shown code.

Answer (score 0):

for array mutation you may use `es6 spread operator` with `slice`, `concat`,

> i) take the array up to the modified index then
>
> ii) append your modified data.
>
> iii) and after that add rest of your data so that your state doesn't mutate.

```
function reducerName(state = initialState, action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_COMPLETED:
        const data = {};
        data.completed = !action.completed;
        let index = state.get('items').findIndex( (item) => { return item.id === action.reminder_id});
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: [...todos.slice(0, index).concat([data]), ...todos.slice(index + 1)],
  };
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting/defining the data variable?

Comment: i have edited the code, you just need to defind the data object like `const data = {};` this

Comment: Why are you taking it out of immutability when you can just use immutable built in functions? The state is immutable and you are returning it mutable? This answer will not work. Where is todos coming from?